# bash + sed - return matches to array, problems with spaces

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to parse the output of a HP RAID controller which returns something like this:

```
Array 1:
    Size: 100GB
    Status: OK
    Caching: Enabled
    OS Status: LOCKED
    Label: asdfasdf
Array 2:
    Size: 100GB
    Status: OK
    Caching: Enabled
    OS Status: LOCKED
    Label: asdfasdf
Array 3:
    Size: 300GB
    Status: OK
    Caching: Enabled
    OS Status: LOCKED
    Label: asdfasdf
Array 4:
    Size: 150GB
    Status: Interim Recovery Mode
    Caching: Enabled
    OS Status: LOCKED
    Label: asdfasdf
```

I want to get all the `Status: (.*)` lines (not the ones that start `<something>Status: (.*)`. I have the follow command which returns the data into an array:

```
array=( `sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*Status:[[:space:]]\([a-zA-Z ]*\)$/\1/p' raid.txt` )    
echo "${array[0]}|${array[1]}|${array[2]}|${array[3]}|${array[4]}|${array[5]}"
num=1
for i in ${array[@]}
do
    echo "${num} ${i}"
    num=$(expr $num + 1)
done
```

This returns the output:

```
OK|OK|OK|Interim|Recovery|Mode
1 OK
2 OK
3 OK
4 Interim
5 Recovery
6 Mode
```

As you can see, the match with spaces gets broken up into 3 separate array keys, when it should only take up one.

I think the `sed` command is my issue, as my test to echo the individual array keys shows they are split at that point. Can anyone suggest how to make sed return the space separated matches into their own key?

Comment: Why should the match with spaces only take up one?

Comment: Because it's a status line, it's a single string. I want to check the output of each status of each block.

Comment: It's just that from the script you have written, I don't understand why you expect a different output.

Comment: I can think of a bunch of ways to do this, but for sake of saving time you can use the hack of replacing that whitespace with underscores  Other option is to set field separator to something other than space., like Mecerra suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a very portable solution, but it works for the sample you provided:

```
cat tmp | grep -v "[[:alnum:]] Status:" | grep -w "Status:" | sed 's/    Status: //' >> file
```

1. With `grep` you filter out the lines containing "[Any alphanumeric character] Status:"
2. Select only the ones containing "Status:"
3. Remove the white spaces and Status: with `sed`
4. With `awk`, prepend the line number

The result looks like:

```
1  OK
2  OK
3  OK
4  Interim Recovery Mode
```

---

If the only thing you want to do is have the array with one status per key:

```
declare -a array
c=0
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    array+=("$line")
    c=$((c+1))
done < "inuptFile"
```

You can test it with:

```
for i in {0..3}; do
    echo "Key $i: ${array[$i]}"
done
```

Which returns:

```
Key 0: OK
Key 1: OK
Key 2: OK
Key 3: Interim Recovery Mode
```

Comment: Thanks - there are other "*Status: OK" lines (e.g. Controller Status), but I can probably filter them all out with some research. It would be ideal if sed just returned the whole string into an array position though!

Comment: I've just tested it, and it seems it's the expansion to an array that is causing the problem. Using your code as follows array=( `cat raid.txt | grep -v "[[:alnum:]] Status:" | grep -w "Status:"  | sed 's/    Status: //'` ) I still get 6 array keys, not 4

Comment: Thanks. I used a hybrid of your code to fit my situation, but the IFS was the key I was missing